# How to use the auto and decltype keywords to ease template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11

I am implementing the Merge sort algorithm. The problem is when I try to use a vector of automatically deduced types within the algorithm.

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TCompare>
void mergeSort(TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCompare criterium)
{
     //...
     auto help = *begin;                // help is a value (not a reference)
     QVector<decltype(help)> leftPart;  // now decltype(help) is also a value
     //...                              // and not a reference
}
```

This works.

But once I make the algorithm pass the `TIterators` by constant reference, I get an error which I never got in my whole life:

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TCompare>
void mergeSort(const TIterator& begin, const TIterator& end, TCompare criterium)
{
     //...
     auto help = *begin;                    // help is a value (not a reference)
     QVector<decltype(help)> leftPart;  // now decltype(help) is also a value
     //...
}
```

results in:

```
In function 'void mergeSort(const TIterator&, const TIterator&, TCompare)':
internal compiler error: in type_unification_real, at cp/pt.c:14176
```

I am using `g++ 4.6.3` on `Ubuntu`

What went wrong?

Comment: "internal compiler error": that looks like a compiler bug to me, honestly

Comment: Shouldn't you use `const auto&` in that case?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Actually I want help to be a value, not a reference, in order to be able to declare a QVector of the same type as help

Comment: @Jasper: definitely. No matter how weird the input, an internal error should not occur.

Comment: Regardless of the error, it’s uncommon to pass iterators as const reference. By value is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An internal compiler error occurs whenever the compiler *fails*, which means that you found a bug. This is the reason while early adoption of new standards is usually called the *bleeding edge*: sometimes, it makes you bleed ;)

There might be something wrong with your code, or there might not. It's not possible to tell from this output alone. What is certain is that the compiler does not support it so you might want to change it instead.

In particular, lookup `std::iterator_traits<>` to see all the things you can deduce from an iterator's type:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type help = *begin;
                                     // ::reference
                                     // ::pointer
                                     // ...
```

By circumventing the automatic deduction, you will probably be able to get past the compiler bug.

---

Note: if you wish to report the bug, which is certainly laudable, you will be asked to produce a preprocessed file reproducing the issue. This file should be as small as possible. It can be generated using `-E` on the gcc command line and generally ends up with the `.ii` extension.

Comment: Thank you! Using the iterator_traits instead worked. It compiled and passed the unit tests.

Comment: Do you need help at all though? What is wrong with QVector< std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type > ?

Comment: @CashCow: a missing `typename` ;) Otherwise, no idea, since I cannot see the rest of the algorithm I cannot know whether `help` is used afterward.